# Concatenate Two Linked Lists

Tags: java, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Write a concatenate() method that takes two linked lists, list1 and list2, and appends list2 onto the end of list1.

For example if the lists were originally:
list1:

```
head-->3-->6-->7-->2-->null
```

list2:

```
head-->9-->5-->3-->null
```

The list1 becomes after concatenation:

```
head-->3-->6-->7-->2-->9-->5-->3-->null

public static void concatenate(LinkedList list1, LinkedList list2) {
   //code


}
```

Comment: Nice problem description! Now, what have you tried, so far? please post your code, pointing the specific problems you're having, so we can help you with it.

Comment: Well my friend, you need to do some more effort. According to this site's rules, you need to provide actual code so we can give you a hand with it. This is not a code-writing service, please be so kind and read this article to have an idea of the proper way to use Stack Overflow: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: `for (Object t: list2) list1.add(t);` ?

Comment: You should post the LinkedList class

Comment: That can be helpful [java combine two linkedlist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6295277/java-combine-two-linkedlist/14090235)

Comment: @Rans Awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Idea: You need a pointer to point to the head of list1. Then move the pointer to the last element of the list1 and assign it to point next to the head of the list2.

```
public class Node  
    { 
int data; 
Node next; 
Node(int d) {data = d; 
             next = null;} 
    } 



public static Node concatenate (Node head1, Node head2) //head1 points to head of list1, head2 points to head of list2
{
                Node temp=null;
                if (head1==NULL) //if the first linked list is empty
                                return (head2);
                if (head2==NULL) //if second linked list is empty
                                return (head1);

                temp=head1;       //place temporary pointer on the first node of the first linked list

                while (temp.next!=NULL) //move p to the last node
                                temp=temp.next;
                temp.next=head2;                           //address of the first node of the second linked list stored in the last node of the first linked list

                return (head1);
}
```